# customize add to cart button in woocommerce product page to direct users

Tags: woocommerce

I'm setting up my own ecommerce website using wordpress-4.2.1, mystile and woocommerce.

What I'm trying to do is when a user is clicking on the "Add to cart" button in a particular product page and a small pop-up windows appear and ask if the user is local or not. If the answer is "yes", then proceed with the add-to-cart process. Else, direct user to a relevant site.

I've been trying to manipulate the button "add to cart" but to no avail. I've been googling for tips but nothing I found helps me so far.

Really appreciate if anyone would be able to help me out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: After doing some research, I modified the add-to-cart.php from wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/ and this still doesn't work. I tried to comment everything out and saved it and then refresh the product page. Then, tried to click "add to cart", it still took me to the next page rather than "doing nothing" which I'd expect it to do.

Comment: Can we have what you have modified ?

Comment: In /wp-content/themes/mystile/functions.php, I added the following code: <code>function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
    return 'http://www.othersite.com/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );<code>. But after saving the file and refresh my page, it gave me a blank page instead after clicking the "add to cart" button.

Comment: This has been resolved. It turned out that I used the wrong PHP code. Instead of using "return 'othersite.com'", header() should have been used.Thank you very much